# View-based “Source List” NSOutlineView not display icons and titles of the items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

After changing NSOutlineView cell-based to view-based, it's not display the icons and titles of file-system tree. Here my code:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"])
        return [(ImageAndTextCell *)cell setTextFieldImage:[item icon]];
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    return [((ConstructorFSEntity *)item) title];
}

- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[FSEntity class]]) {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
    } else {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
    }
}
```

And I've one more question. How to put the enumerated items (array of file system's item) to the cell "DataCell", and "HeaderCell" declare as parent folder (group) and assign it a title (for example, @ "Root Folder") and the path of the class. Because, now previous view-based method,  displayed enumerated item only in "HeaderCell" or "DataCell" and when I trying assign to "HeaderCell" a some value,  the app crashing. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the titles and icons of items, you need just to change this method

`- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item`

as follows:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    if (![item isKindOfClass:[FSEntity class]]) {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
    } else {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
        [(ImageAndTextCell *)cellView.textField.cell setTextFieldImage:[item icon]];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = [((FSEntity *)item) title];
        return cellView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSTabelCellView` provide already a property `imageView` therefore you can set the image just by setting `cellView.imageView.objectValue = [item icon]`. You don't need the ImageAndTextCell class from the SourceView example.